# Problem passing frame from setting.plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have defined frame in my settings.plist and accesing it in my class as a string while passing it gives an error:

Here's the code:

```
NSString * frame = [selectable objectForKey:@"Frame"]; 
[self selectButtons:@"Select." andFrame:frame andValue:goal];


-(void)selectButtons:(NSString *)text andFrame:(NSString *)frame andValue:(int)goal
{

    UIColor * c = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIFont * font = BUTTON_TITLE;
    UIColor * f = DESC_Color_White;
    select = [ApplicationHelpers buttonWithTitle:text andBgColor:c andTitleColor:f andTitleFont:font];
    CGRect frame1 = frame; -------->>>>>> gives error here
    select.frame = frame1;

    UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scneariosButtonSmall1.png"];
    UIImage * strechableButtonImage = [buttonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [select setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [select addTarget:self action:@selector(selectClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:select];

}
```

Please give me some hint on this???

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

An NSString cannot be implicitly converted between a CGRect. You need to use functions like [NSStringFromCGRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGRect) and [CGRectFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectFromString) to do the conversion.

```
CGRect frame1 = CGRectFromString(frame);

...

// when you need to save the CGRect:
NSString* frameString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame1);
```

Comment: This worked but the only thing is i am passing my frame as CGRectMake(20, 30 ,150, 54) and while debugging i checked its not giving any value. I mean x,y, width and height are all coming zero.So do i need to define the frame in my settings file differently.

Comment: @Ashu: You mean the string `frame` is `@"CGRectMake(20, 30 ,150, 54)"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign a string to a `CGRect` variable and expect that it works. You have to convert one type into the other. Depending on what format your frame string is in, you might be able to use the `CGRectFromString()` function (use `NSStringFromCGRect()`) to create a corresponding string from a `CGRect`. Or you have to parse the string manually yourself.

Or, perhaps even better, wrap your frame value in an `NSValue` with `+[NSValue valueWithCGRect:]` and `-[NSValue CGRectValue]`.